# electricsheep installation in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: software-installation

Can anyone please tell how to install [electricsheep](http://www.electricsheep.org/) in ubuntu 15.04?
I could not find any package in synaptic

Answer (score 1):

You can check the following PPA for the latest version of packages:

https://launchpad.net/~ichthyo/+archive/ubuntu/zeug

Answer (score 0):

There is no package for Ubuntu 15.04 and I have tried to compile it, with **no success** in my *Vivid*:

1. Build the application via `debuild`

   - Clone the source code

     ```
     mkdir -p ~/src
     cd ~/src
     bzr branch lp:ubuntu/vivid/electricsheep
     ```
   - Build the application

     ```
     cd ~/src/electricsheep
     ./configure
     debuild
     ```
   - and install

     ```
     % sudo dpkg -i ../electricsheep_2.7\~b12+svn20091224-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb 
     dpkg: warning: downgrading electricsheep from 2.7b12-1 to 2.7~b12+svn20091224-1ubuntu3
     (Reading database ... 662292 files and directories currently installed.)
     Preparing to unpack .../electricsheep_2.7~b12+svn20091224-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
     Unpacking electricsheep (2.7~b12+svn20091224-1ubuntu3) over (2.7b12-1) ...
     dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of electricsheep:
      electricsheep depends on libavcodec53 (>= 4:0.7-1) | libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7-1); however:
       Package libavcodec53 is not installed.
       Package libavcodec-extra-53:amd64 is not installed.
      electricsheep depends on libavformat53 (>= 4:0.7-1) | libavformat-extra-53 (>= 4:0.7-1); however:
       Package libavformat53 is not installed.
       Package libavformat-extra-53 is not installed.

     dpkg: error processing package electricsheep (--install):
      dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
     Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47ubuntu1) ...
     Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-3ubuntu1) ...
     Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
     Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
     Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
     Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
     Errors were encountered while processing:
      electricsheep
     ```

     Doesn't work, there could be some dependencies installed, but not all.
2. Build via `make`

   - remove the previous source folder

     ```
     sudo rm -r ~/src/electricsheep
     ```
   - Clone again

     ```
     mkdir -p ~/src
     cd ~/src
     bzr branch lp:ubuntu/vivid/electricsheep
     ```
   - Build

     ```
     cd ~/src/electricsheep
     ./configure
     ```

     and start `make`, but… no success

     ```
     % make
     make  all-am
     make[1]: Entering directory '/home/aboettger/tmp/electricsheep'
     gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\"/usr/local/share/electricsheep\" -g -O2 -c electricsheep.c
     electricsheep.c: In function ‘copy_out_file’:
     electricsheep.c:673:6: error: ‘CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
       if (CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO == enc->codec_type) {
           ^
     electricsheep.c:673:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
     electricsheep.c:699:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
       ofmt = guess_format(NULL, fname, NULL);
            ^
     electricsheep.c:706:5: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
       st = av_new_stream(output_ctx, output_ctx->nb_streams);
          ^
     electricsheep.c:707:4: error: ‘AVStream’ has no member named ‘stream_copy’
       st->stream_copy = 1;
         ^
     electricsheep.c:726:39: error: ‘URL_WRONLY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
       if (url_fopen(&output_ctx->pb, pipe, URL_WRONLY) < 0) {
                                            ^
     electricsheep.c:741:22: error: ‘PKT_FLAG_KEY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
              ipkt.flags & PKT_FLAG_KEY))
                           ^
     electricsheep.c:742:6: warning: ‘destruct’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:994) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
           opkt.destruct= av_destruct_packet;
           ^
     electricsheep.c:742:6: warning: ‘av_destruct_packet’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/libavcodec/avcodec.h:3294) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     electricsheep.c: In function ‘update_server_sheep’:
     electricsheep.c:1774:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘size_t’ [-Wformat=]
       if (debug > 1) fprintf(logout, "list read loop len=%d\n", len);
       ^
     Makefile:316: recipe for target 'electricsheep.o' failed
     make[1]: *** [electricsheep.o] Error 1
     make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/aboettger/tmp/electricsheep'
     Makefile:217: recipe for target 'all' failed
     make: *** [all] Error 2
     ```

---

**Therefore**, not installable at a reasonable cost.

*Sorry to the harbinger of bad news.*